# "client secrets" that aren't & open source

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

According to [the Google Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-client), an application needs a so-called "client secret" in order to interact with the Google Drive SDK -- even if, as in the case of a client-side JavaScript app, the code is plain for all to see. (Of course, it's not really that much safer in any other client-side code, it just makes for a bit more work to find the "secret"...)

So, um:

1. How is it okay to distribute these "secrets" inside applications?
2. Is there any reason why that logic wouldn't apply to open source computer programs?
3. BONUS: Wouldn't it make more sense to just use user-based authentication for such apps, without pretending to authenticate the app as being a specific app?

Comment: These are good and interesting questions, but this is not the forum for this kind of discussion.

Comment: @Stan: Any idea what is?

Comment: honestly, no.  I wish I could be of more help, but maybe a moderator will poke their head in here and tell you.  I would start with the 'Help' drop-down in the top right corner of your browser window.  Looks liek they have a tour of the site, which will probably outline each forum's rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst it's true that a Client Secret is generated for all apps that consume Google services, the Client Secret is never used by a browser/javascript app. Typically a browser-app (I use the phrase "browser-app" instead of "Javascript app" because a server node.js app is also using Javascript) would authenticate and authorize using the gapi library described here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthauthorize. As you can see, Client Secret is never used.

So, picking out your questions ...

1. It isn't OK, don't do it, no need, see above.
2. See 1
3. You're conflating authenticating the user with authenticating the app. Both are needed, each for different purposes. In the case of a browser app, the authentication is done using a combination of the client ID, verified against the http origin (which the developer has previously declared to Google). Once the app is authenticated, we can then move on to authenticate the user by leveraging the OAuth authorization mechanism in conjunction with an extant Google session.

Comment: I could have sworn that the page I linked in my question showed a place to fill in the client secret the last time I looked at it, but what do you know: it only seems to be mentioned in a section heading, nowhere else...

Comment: As for #3, I'm not conflating them; I'm saying that authenticating an app is impossible in general because there's nothing to prevent an app lying about what it is. (JavaScript that is actually served from a website is obviously going to be somewhat restricted in what it can do, but there really isn't anything to prevent a browser extension or non-web app from impersonating such a browser-app, is there?)

Comment: On your last question, yes you're correct. Perhaps "identifying" would be more accurate than "authenticating".